# Looking to combine to REGEXMATCH queries in a Google Sheets ArrayFormula - If contains X and does not contain Y

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm Looking to combine to REGEXMATCH queries in a Google Sheets ArrayFormula - If contains X and does not contain Y but failing... :(  Any help would be appreciated.

=filter(A2:A1001,((ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A2:A1001,L34)))),(ARRAYFORMULA(not(REGEXMATCH(A2:A1001,L34)))))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

make sure L34 is not in both conditions... try:

```
=FILTER(A2:A1001; REGEXMATCH(A2:A1001&""; L34); 
              NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A1001&""; L35)))))
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did it!  I was so close.  The proverbial ' instead of a `.  ;)